# AutoITLibrary = Automating Simple Windows GUI Application

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, ui-automation, autoit

could anybody please help me in automating the GUI/UI of a simple Windows application using the Robot Framework AutoITLibrary? I've done it using just the AutoIT tool, but can't seem to get it to work using the AutoITLibrary.

I've tried my syntax below, but no luck. Essentially, all I want to do is launch the application, and go Next >> Next >> Finish. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | AutoItLibrary


*** Variables ***
| ${P4Vx64} | C:\\Temp\\setup.exe
| ${Title} | Sample Application


*** Test Cases ***
| Install
| | AutoItLibrary.Run | ${P4Vx64}
| | Control Click | ${Title} | &Next | Button6
| | Control Click | ${Title} | &Next | Button5 
| | Control Click | ${Title} | &Finish | Button3
```

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? Do you get errors? Does the application start? What is it doing that you're not expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/)? The script should look very simple and readable:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application()
app.start_("C:\\Temp\\setup.exe")
mainWindow = app.SampleApplication
mainWindow.Wait('ready')
mainWindow['&Next'].ClickInput()
mainWindow['&Next'].ClickInput()
mainWindow['&Finish'].ClickInput()
mainWindow.WaitNot('visible')
```